# Excel combine multiple rows with ID

Tags: microsoft-excel

Okay so first I have two columns in excel like this:

```
ID                                      Main Image
2e0f3f8f-adcc-4bd9-b992-dbc0aff221f7    376703_in_pp.jpg
c34b52ad-2ff5-472b-b011-f9b566e894a3    373880_in_pp.jpg
0ab38a23-1c58-45d6-9322-78b2e62d4c52    363441_in_pp.jpg
```

Then I have another two columsn like this:

```
ID                                      Sub Image
2e0f3f8f-adcc-4bd9-b992-dbc0aff221f7    376703_in_pp.jpg
2e0f3f8f-adcc-4bd9-b992-dbc0aff221f7    376703_fr_pp.jpg
2e0f3f8f-adcc-4bd9-b992-dbc0aff221f7    376703_bk_pp.jpg
2e0f3f8f-adcc-4bd9-b992-dbc0aff221f7    376703_ou_pp.jpg
2e0f3f8f-adcc-4bd9-b992-dbc0aff221f7    376703_cu_pp.jpg
c34b52ad-2ff5-472b-b011-f9b566e894a3    373880_in_pp.jpg
c34b52ad-2ff5-472b-b011-f9b566e894a3    373880_in_pp.jpg
c34b52ad-2ff5-472b-b011-f9b566e894a3    373880_fr_pp.jpg
c34b52ad-2ff5-472b-b011-f9b566e894a3    373880_bk_pp.jpg
c34b52ad-2ff5-472b-b011-f9b566e894a3    373880_ou_pp.jpg
0ab38a23-1c58-45d6-9322-78b2e62d4c52    363441_in_pp.jpg
0ab38a23-1c58-45d6-9322-78b2e62d4c52    363441_fr_pp.jpg
0ab38a23-1c58-45d6-9322-78b2e62d4c52    363441_bk_pp.jpg
0ab38a23-1c58-45d6-9322-78b2e62d4c52    363441_ou_pp.jpg
0ab38a23-1c58-45d6-9322-78b2e62d4c52    363441_ou_pp.jpg
```

What I need is to have the final result look like this:

```
ID                                      Main Image
2e0f3f8f-adcc-4bd9-b992-dbc0aff221f7    376703_in_pp.jpg|376703_in_pp.jpg|376703_fr_pp.jpg|376703_bk_pp.jpg|376703_ou_pp.jpg|376703_cu_pp.jpg
c34b52ad-2ff5-472b-b011-f9b566e894a3    373880_in_pp.jpg|373880_in_pp.jpg|373880_in_pp.jpg|373880_fr_pp.jpg|373880_bk_pp.jpg|373880_ou_pp.jpg
0ab38a23-1c58-45d6-9322-78b2e62d4c52    363441_in_pp.jpg|363441_in_pp.jpg|363441_fr_pp.jpg|363441_bk_pp.jpg|363441_ou_pp.jpg|363441_ou_pp.jpg
```

Basically I need to have excel combine into a single row all of the images which have the same ID and each one separated with a | sign. Any excel experts out there able to help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Is VBA an option or do you only want formulas?

Comment: I'm a really basic excel noob, I know how to use basic formulas but I've never used VBA before. Which solution is easier and that works well?